# Python web application internationalization

Tags: python, internationalization, bottle

I'm writing a small python web application (personal KB management mostly for learning), with the good `bottle.py` micro framework, yet a question blows my mind:

What is the best way to provide Internalization in a Web application? Should I use the python `gettext` or something else, should I write a single template full of`{{translatethis}}` or is there a more elegant approach?

Should i process the translation directly from python or use some JS magic to re-translate the templates on the fly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could save each translation on a separate file like so:

english.txt

```
greeting hi
name bob
```

arabic.txt

```
greeting اهلاً
name بوب
```

You then load the required translation into a dictionary by iterating over and splitting each line. In this example, loading english.txt should return something like `translation = {'greeting': 'hi', 'name': 'bob'}`.
Then render a template using this dictionary by calling `template('{{greeting}} {{name}}!', translation)`. Also remember to set `dir="rtl"` in your HTML if you are using right-to-left languages.

Comment: Look's like gettext is already doing what you say. I'm looking into a way of avoiding creating a template full of {{translateme}}

Comment: I would suggest sticking to templates. If you make one html file per language, then any time you need to make a change you need to do so for every language. You will end up with the same problem (if not worse) if you hard-code the strings in your python file. gettext was made to solve the problem you are facing, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Yeah that seems the best option, didn't think about something simple as that. My bad, a tpl for each language and then gettext for the inapp logic. Thanks for the suggestion